# How to add todo in GitLab comment to increase todo number?

Tags: gitlab

If todo is added to description it increase todo number but not in comment. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Do you mean tasks? AFAIK only stuff in the description counts. You may read more [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/29190)

Comment: if someone mentions you in a comment, it adds it to your list of "to do". Admittedly, not sure about what happens if you're mentioned in both the description and the comment. It may not count it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround.  There is an open issue about this now, as StepTNT commented. The current issue is: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17441